# Plotting sized squares on Google-maps

Tags: r

I need to plot many squares of different colors on Google-maps, these commands work well:

```
library(RgoogleMaps)
Map <- GetMap.bbox(bb$lonR, bb$latR, zoom=zoom, maptype="terrain", NEWMAP=TRUE)
tmp <- PlotOnStaticMap(lat=tbl_to_plot$lat, lon=tbl_to_plot$lon, cex=2, pch=15, col=tbl_to_plot$color, MyMap=Map, add=TRUE, NEWMAP=FALSE, FUN=points)
```

Choosing `pch=15` results in the points becoming squares (good). The challenge is that I need each square to be exactly 100x100 meters big, and as the underlying maps can be of different zoom, it needs to be set automatically. I suppose it is the cex-value I should change, but I don't understand what unit it has.

Thanks to all R-users here at Stack Overflow for a fantastic source of help!

Comment: reproducible code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PlotOnStaticMap` function uses base graphics, in which sizes of points are a little fuzzy.  If you need to accurately specify the size of your squares, you need to use a grid-based graphics package (either `lattice` or `ggplot2`).

There's a good demo of using `RgoogleMaps` with `ggplot2` [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Crime-in-Downtown-Houston,-Texas-%3a-Combining-ggplot2-and-Google-Maps).

Comment: Thanks! The link has the info I needed.